# How to have multiple statement for every condition in an if function?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am writing a code in python 3.5.4 that requires more than one statement for every condition that I set in an if clause
for example:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30
n=int(input('please enter a number: '))
if n>0:
    print(d=a+b)
    print(e=a-b)
    print(f=a*b)
else:
    print(0)
```

But if the first condition is met, only first statement is implemented.
please tell me how to implement all 3 lines.

Comment: you don't need to define variables when you are printing. You should just call `print(a+b)` and such.

Comment: thank you so much
but actually it was an assignment from my teacher and it surprises me to see how easy it is solved.
the actual question was:
how to implement more than one line of code if the condition is met
i guess she talked about : "{ }" and "end"

Comment: @ehsun, "{}" and "end" sounds more like Ruby syntax than Python.

Answer (score 1):

Its not about the if statement. You cant assign and print the variables in the same step.

Use this instead:

```
a=10
b=20
c=30
n=int(input('please enter a number: '))
if n>0:
    d=a+b
    print(d)
    e=a-b
    print(e)
    f=a*b
    print(f)
else:
    print(0)
```